# Content revision issue for every code deployment

Tags: craft4, deployment, content

The content reversion issue was reported during the production deployment of a new module on the Craft CMS site.

To address this issue, we suspect the below deployment scripts are causing the content reversion problem. So, we manually executed these deployment scripts on the staging server including the following:
**./craft migrate/all
./craft project-config/apply
./craft clear-caches/data
./craft project-config/rebuild**

During this investigation, we were able to replicate the content reversion issue specifically while running the **php craft project-config/apply** command in the terminal. Below is the screenshot for your reference,
[image]

Therefore, we suspect that there might be an inherent glitch within the Craft CMS. Below are the Application & server details of the site, please help us to understand the issue better and to avoid this kind of issue in the future.

1. PHP version 8.2.10
2. OS version  Linux 5.15.0-1044-aws
3. Database driver & version   MySQL 5.7.42
4. Craft edition & version Craft Pro 4.5.3

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable, so kinda pointless. Beyond that, what is your question? “The content revison issue…” wth does that mean?

Comment: I think he means that when running `php craft project-config/apply` the matrixBlockType was removed unexpectedly

Comment: Yes, correct, this script php craft project-config/apply is added into the codecommit deployment and whenever this script runs during the deployment the recent content changes have been reverted.

Comment: I don't see the issue. You removed a field, pushed project config changes to your server and then ran project-config/apply so the field was removed. If you didn't intend that field to be removed then you should revert the changes to project config that removed that field.